# How to use existing Masterpage.Master in asp.net web project to another MVC4 _layout.cshtml project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, master-pages

Please help me out that I have an existing project with Masterpage.master file and I want to use that design to new MVC4 project. so how can we incorporate this functionality. Please help.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what the question really is. Could you write what exactly do you want to do, what have you tried, and what problems did you find?

Comment: Using Masterpage of existing asp.net project which is developed into asp.net 4.5 framework into a new project of MVC4